# UNIX, Assign value to a variable in C or KornShell (ksh)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

When I use bash to run the following code, it will assign the value 5 to the var1.

```
var1=$(awk '$1>$3{ print "5"}' newfile2)
echo $var1
```

But when I use this same code in banana or something, it gives me error. Can someone please tell me if there is some other way I can write this code so I can run it using the C or KornShell (ksh) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C shell, use

```
set var=`....`
```

For bash/ksh

```
var1=$(awk '$1>$3{ print "5"}' newfile2)
```

Comment: The question is, why would anyone want to write code for csh rather than bash? Clearly, csh's age combined with its annoying and limited ad-hoc parser is the reason shells like bash became popular, isn't it?

Comment: you shell tell that to OP. Put your comments in his question. AFAIK, his teacher said csh/ksh as well as bash.

Comment: Thanks ghostdog for the new code. I try it with both bash and the other one. now it doesn't work with none of them. it simply doesn't assign any value to var1 nor compare the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks and the set command for csh.

```
set var1=`awk '$1>$3{ print "5"}' newfile2`
echo $var1
```

Comment: Thanks.  when I use this code, it did not assign any values for the var1.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are no spaces before and after the variable name.
so,

```
var1=`ls`
```

is what you need. But, if you have

```
var = `ls`
```

you will get errors.

So, your code should be:

```
var1=`awk '$1>$3{ print "5"}' newfile2`
echo $var1
```

Make sure you are in BASH shell, not C or TCSH.